# Is healthful considered an acceptable synonym of healthy?

Tags: synonyms

To my ear, *healthful* does not sound right. This could well be geographical bias on my part.   Is it now a valid alternative to *healthy*?  Does it have another meaning?

Comment: How does the distinction between *healthy* and *healthful* compare to other *noun-y*, *noun-ful*, and *noun-ish* constructs?

Comment: healthful : healthy :: nauseating : nauseous.  QED.  Vote to close.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Healthy* means "in a state of well-being."

*Healthful* means "promoting or contributing to one's healthiness."  (Apparently it used to be a suitable synonym for "healthy" but I don't believe it is widely considered such anymore.)

So, to re-word the old adage, you could say that an apple a day is healthful; but you wouldn't say that you are healthful unless you're trying to convince a reluctant cannibal to consume you.

Comment: So the "healthy eating" we are always being hectored about should really be "healthful eating"?

Comment: I've never once heard *healthful* used as a word in British English. Perhaps within other dialects, though? It may have died out in usage here. Sounds a bit jargony, in any case.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it's a cromulent neologism.

Comment: Good use of "cromulent"!

Comment: You might have thought to embiggen your answer a little, though.

Comment: @Robusto: Using teh google? Meh.

Answer (score 2):

To my ear, "healthful" refers to something that promotes health, like a "healthful diet" or a "healthful climate," whereas someone who eats a healthful diet has a better chance of being "healthy."  In everyday speech, we often hear "healthy" used (incorrectly?) in place of "healthful."